# Python-mysql-connector: cursor.fetch on stopped mysql slave fails

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I have searched for days to find the cause of this issue but with no luck, I have the following block of python code that should retrieve the status of the slave mysql server after it is stopped.
It works perfectly when the slave is running. However the craziest part is that when the slave is stopped, it returns the following error:

> Failed getting warnings; MySQL Connection not available.

from this line:

> print(len(crsr.fetchall()))

WHY?

```python
conn = connectdb(hostname, dbuser, dbpass, dbname)
crsr = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
crsr.execute("SHOW SLAVE STATUS")
print(len(crsr.fetchall()))
row = list(crsr.fetchall())[0]
slave_status = row['Slave_SQL_Running_State']
if slave_status is None:
    print("This is not a slave")
else:
    print(slave_status)
```

I have tried this locally on normal mysql and on mysql RDS instances:
python version 3.8.5
local mysql  Ver 8.0.21 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
RDS mysql 5.7.28 for linux x64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Comment: Not sure why, but how about just using a try / except to handle that error? As long as it works when the slave is running, then you know that an error means it's not running, right? Also, RDS mysql supports 8.0.21 as of 10/23, so you could be using the same mysql versions between local and aws development.

Comment: @YannStoneman, yes I have added try / except eventually to handle this and finish my code, but this is very weird case. Maybe we should add it to the connector repo on GH